# How to return response from http module in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback, node.js-connect

How do I return the response value, **access_token**, to a variable for use elsewhere? It yields undefined if I try to log its value outside of `res.on('data')` listener.

```
const http = require('http');
const authGrantType = 'password';
const username = '[The username]';
const password = '[The password]';
const postData = `grant_type=${authGrantType}&username=${username}&password=${password}`;
const options = {
  hostname: '[URL of the dev site, also omitting "http://" from the string]',
  port: 80,
  path: '[Path of the token]',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
};
const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`); // Print out the status
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`); // Print out the header
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (access_token) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${access_token}`); // This prints out the generated token. This piece of data needs to be exported elsewhere
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

The token value is logged to the console by the line that reads: `` console.log(`BODY: ${access_token}`); `` The issue is with trying to extract this value to be used elsewhere. Rather than having to encapsulate every new function with an `HTTP` call inside the other call that was required to supersede it and provide it with a response before it could continue. It's sort of enforcing synchronicity in NodeJS.

Comment: have you tried storing it in a variable?

Comment: Yes, I stored access_token to a variable and logged it to the console, it read undefined. I even tried var obj = {}; And simply added access_token to obj. Still responds with the same issue. Perhaps the procedure that I followed was incorrect. Not quite sure.

Comment: declare `var testVar;` above the `const req = ....`. then do `testvar = access_token;` inside the `res.on('data', ...)`

Comment: Just tried that. When I log the value of testVar, it reads undefined.

Comment: thats strange, try changing `const req = ...` to `var req = ...` and see if that works

Comment: I replaced `const` with `var`. And the same issue persists. Nevertheless, the token is logged to the console by the line that reads: `console.log(\`BODY: ${access_token}\`);` The issue is with trying to extract this value for usage elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should encapsutale your code with a promise

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', (d) => {
              resolve(d);
            })
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            reject(e);
        });

        req.write(data);
        req.end();
    })
```